# check Server is Reachable before each api call? [Integrate with API]

Tags: api, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have an api module class. it looks like this

```
// General api to acces data from web
import ApiConstants from './ApiConstants';
export default function api(path,params,method){

    let options;
        options = Object.assign({headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }},{ method: method }, params ? { body: JSON.stringify(params) } : null );


    return fetch(ApiConstants.BASE_URL+path, options)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then( json => json)
        .catch((error) => error);
    });
}
```

I know we can use the following snippet to check whether my backend server is reachable.

```
 const isAvailable = () => {
    const timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 300, 'Request timed out');
    });

    const request = fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/5');

    return Promise
        .race([timeout, request])
        .then(response => alert('It worked :)'))
        .catch(error => alert('It timed out :('));
}

isAvailable();
```

> But how can i combine this two calls in an efficient manner?. I would like to check whether server is reachable before each call?

**PS**: My API Server is available only using **vpn** even though network is available. So the api call can only be made after checking the server reachability.

> Fetch in React Native will not timeout if the server is unreachable (Timeout not working)

**Edit**: As @jevakallio mentioned in his answer .. adding the server code will only make the code more complex. Even though the timeout is much higher in react native the best way is to use the logic mentioned below(@jevakallio) rather than using a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to check that your server is available?

Instead, you could just try to fire the actual request every time, and if the request fails, check the error code to deduct if the issue was due to server availability or some other error.

Something like:

```
const NO_RESPONSE_CODE = 0;

return fetch(ApiConstants.BASE_URL+path, options)
    .then(resp => {
      if (resp.ok) {
        return resp.json();
      } else {

        if (resp.status === NO_RESPONSE_CODE) {
          // server unavailable
          return Promise.reject(new Error('Server unavailable'));
        } else {
          // handle other API errors here, implementation
          // depends on your response format
        }
      }
    })
    .then( json => json)
    .catch((error) => error);
```

The reasons this mechanism is preferrable is:

1. Avoid unnecessary network calls
2. Reduce the time it takes to get a successful response by eliminating the pre-check
3. The result is more reliable. Even if you check that server is available by making a pre-check request, there is no guarantee that the server is still available when you make the actual follow-up request. Mobile networks can be surprisingly fickle, and your device radio can drop off a network between the requests.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise the request would hang forever. From the point of view of the network stack, typically a network resource that is behind a VPN would simply "not exist" when you're not connected to said VPN, and it would immediately return. I'm curious what is up -are you able to share a URL to that resource to test that?

Comment: I cant share the url. The problem is RN uses fetch which doesn't have a timeout. But just like u said adding a server reachability code will only increase the complexity .. I will try to find another way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

```
const isAvailable = () => {
    const timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 300, 'Request timed out');
    });

    const request = fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/5');

    return Promise
        .race([timeout, request])
        .then(response => alert('It worked :)'))
        .catch(error => alert('It timed out :('));
}

/ General api to acces data from web
import ApiConstants from './ApiConstants';
export default function api(path,params,method, sssid){

    let options;
        options = Object.assign({headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }},{ method: method }, params ? { body: JSON.stringify(params) } : null );


    return isAvailable().then(() => fetch(ApiConstants.BASE_URL+path, options))
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then( json => json)
        .catch((error) => error);
    });
}
```

calling isAvailable always before calling fetch. once isAvailable resolves you can call fetch api and return its promise in then.